# What is the difference between "play at" and "play upon"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> - We are playing at cards.
> - She is playing upon the piano.

In both sentences, why are we using prepositions ?

Comment: The prepositions aren't commonly used in either of those examples these days. They are, however, correct. There are plenty of other phrasal verbs with play. Have a search.

Comment: As you can see from this Ngram, "playing *at* cards" is the way people spoke in the 17th and 18th centuries. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=playing+at+cards%2Cplaying+cards&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaying%20at%20cards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaying%20cards%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

### You should not use a proposition in either example

> We are playing cards.

And

> She is playing the piano.

Note, though:

> She is playing **a tune** on the piano.

Answer (score 0):

These are older usages, once standard, now unusual although not incorrect. I would expect to see them in a historical novel set in the 18th century, particularly among upper class people of that time. It reminds me of a Jane Austen novel.

However, the form "playing at X" is still sometimes used when X is not a game or a  musical instrument, but is something that the person is doing amateurishly or carelessly. It carries a negative connotation. For example:

- > John is playing at matchmaking
- > Jane is playing at business.

The implication is that John and Jane don't know what there are doing, and are not putting much effort into it. One might say "playing matchmaker" or "playing businesswoman" with the same meaning and implication.